# Iterable and .db file searcher that imports data

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

This Program is a tool that allows me to import data from files that may not be easy to read just by opening; such as .db files which are wayyyyy to hard to understand just by opening the file in something like notepad and viewing the contents (this is meant for small files).

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

class SqliteGui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title(string = 'Advanced Data Import tool')

        #placement
        w = 515
        h = 350
        ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
        master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))

        #creation of widgets


        #entrys
        self.pathentry = ttk.Entry(master )
        self.pathentry.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 6,   sticky = 'we') 
        self.catentry = ttk.Entry(master )
        self.catentry.grid(row = 2 , column = 1 ,   sticky = 'we') 
        self.tableentry = ttk.Entry(master )
        self.tableentry.grid(row = 2 , column = 4 ,   sticky = 'we') 
        #buttons
        self.submitbutton = ttk.Button(master, text = 'Submit',command = sqlite_file_searcher)
        self.submitbutton.grid(row = 2 , column = 5 , sticky = 'we')
        self.clearbutton = ttk.Button(master, text = 'Clear' , command = sqlclearlistbox).grid(row = 6 , column = 1, sticky = 'we')
        self.backbutton = ttk.Button(master , text = 'Back <--' , command = backwards).grid(row = 7 , column = 1,  sticky = 'we')
        #labels
        self.pathlabel = tk.Label(master, text = 'File Name(sqlite db)' , fg = 'Green').grid(row = 0 , sticky = 'we' , column = 0)
        self.select = tk.Label (master , text = 'SELECT' , fg = 'green').grid(row = 2 , sticky = 'we' , column = 0)
        self.fromlabel = tk.Label(master , text = 'FROM' , fg = 'green').grid(row = 2 , sticky = 'we' , column =3 )
        self.credit = tk.Label(master, text = 'Created By: Ronald Colyar' , fg= 'green').grid(row  = 6 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' )
        #listbox
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(master , bd = 0)
        self.listbox.grid(row = 5 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' , columnspan = 6 , padx = 4 , pady = 4 )
        #message
        self.status = tk.Message(master , text = "Status: Good" , fg = 'Green')
        self.status.grid(row = 7 , column = 0,  sticky = 'we')



        self.titlebar = tk.Menu(master)
        self.help = tk.Menu(master , tearoff = False)
        self.help.add_command(label = 'Help' , command =help_mthd )

        self.titlebar.add_cascade(label = 'Help Options' ,menu = self.help)
        master.config(menu = self.titlebar)

    def statusUpdate(self, msg ,color):
        self.status.config(text = msg)
        self.status.config(fg = color)

class MainPage:
    def __init__(self , master) :
        self.master = master
        master.title(string = 'Data Import tool')
        #configuration of window
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        #placement
        w = 505
        h = 237
        ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
        master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
        #creation of widgets
        self.pathlabel = tk.Label(master, text = 'Path To File(.csv, .txt ,default iterable files)' , fg = 'Green').grid(row = 0 , sticky = 'we' , column = 0)
        self.pathentry = ttk.Entry(master )
        self.pathentry.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' , pady = 4 , padx = 4) 
        self.submitbutton = ttk.Button(master, text = 'Submit' , command = defaultfilesearcher)
        self.submitbutton.grid(row = 1 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(master , bd = 0)
        self.listbox.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' , columnspan = 2 , padx = 4 , pady = 4 )
        self.credit = tk.Label(master, text = 'Created By: Ronald Colyar' , fg= 'green').grid(row  = 3 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' )
        self.clearbutton = ttk.Button(master , text = 'Clear' ,command = mainclearlistbox).grid(row = 3 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.statusmessage = tk.Label(master, text = 'Status: Good' , fg = 'Green')
        self.statusmessage.grid(row = 0 , column = 1 ,sticky = 'we')

        #menus
        self.titlebar = tk.Menu(master)
        self.advanced = tk.Menu(master , tearoff = False )
        self.advanced.add_command(label = 'Advanced Sqlite' , command = Sqlite_main)


        #config
        self.titlebar.add_cascade(label = 'sqlite' , menu = self.advanced)  
        master.config(menu = self.titlebar)
    def statusUpdate(self,msg , color):
        self.statusmessage.config(text =msg , fg = color)

def backwards():
    second_window.withdraw()
    Main_window.deiconify()

def defaultfilesearcher():
    Path = str(Main_Object.pathentry.get())
    #row identifier
    Number_of_row = 0
    #checking if error occurs
    try:
         open(Path, 'r') 
         errorcheck = False
    except FileNotFoundError:
         errorcheck = True


    #if a error doesnt occur
    if errorcheck == False:
        Main_Object.statusUpdate('Status: Good' , 'green')
        with open(Path , 'r') as f :
            contents = f.readlines()

            for i in contents:
                Number_of_row +=1
                #inserting the data
                Main_Object.listbox.insert('end' , '#'+str(Number_of_row)+': '+str(i) )

    else:
        Main_Object.statusUpdate('File Not Found Try again' , 'red')
def sqlite_file_searcher():

    global sqlite_obj
    #db file
    conn = sqlite3.connect(str(sqlite_obj.pathentry.get()))
    c = conn.cursor()
    #checking for an error
    try:
        results = c.execute("SELECT " + str(sqlite_obj.catentry.get()) +" FROM " + str(sqlite_obj.tableentry.get() ))
        checkresults = True
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        checkresults = False
    #the handling of the error check
    if checkresults == True:
        for i in results:
            sqlite_obj.listbox.insert(0, i)
            sqlite_obj.statusUpdate("Status: Good" , 'Green')
    else:
        #updating user if error occur
        sqlite_obj.statusUpdate('Status :Error: Please Check Entered Information, View the help tab for assistance' , 'Red')


    conn.close()
def help_mthd():
    help_win = tk.Tk()
    message = tk.Message(help_win , text= 'Welcome to the help window , 1. For the formatted database(sqlite) , you are selecting from a certain table inside of the .db file , if the table doesnt exist or the thing you are searching for doesnt exist, you will get an error verify that your information is correct if you are having a problem , 2..db File must be in same folder as the file searcher executable')
    message.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
def Main():
    global Main_window, Main_Object
    Main_window = tk.Tk()
    Main_Object = MainPage(Main_window)
    Main_window.mainloop()
def Sqlite_main():
    global Main_window, sqlite_obj ,second_window
    Main_window.withdraw()
    second_window = tk.Tk()
    sqlite_obj = SqliteGui(second_window)
def sqlclearlistbox():
    sqlite_obj.listbox.delete(0 , 'end')
def mainclearlistbox():
    Main_Object.listbox.delete(0 , 'end')
if  __name__ == "__main__" :
    Main()
```

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use classe more

Classes make it much easier to organize GUI code. It's good that you've created a couple of classes, though about a third of your code lives outside of a class. I would recommend using classes for almost all code except the last couple of lines.

### Use pep8 guidelines more

You have functions and variables that violate [PEP8 naming guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) (`Main`, `Sqlite_main`, `Main_window`, etc), making your code a bit harder to understand. I recommend sticking to these guidelines.

### Don't use wildcard imports

Use `import tkinter as tk` and then prefix all tk classes and commands with `tk.` (eg: `tk.Tk()`, `tk.Frame(...)`, etc). It looks like you're doing that everwhere, but you're importing tkinter twice: once with `from tkinter import *` and then with `import tkinter as tk`. Just do the latter.

### Don't create multiple instances of Tk

Tkinter is designed so that you have exactly one instance of `Tk` for the life of the program. You have three. You should always create only one instance, and call `mainloop` exactly once. Each time you create a new instance it initiates a new embedded tcl interpreter, and each interpreter cannot talk to any other.

If you need additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

### Group layout codes together

Code like this is hard to read and visualize:

```
self.pathentry = ttk.Entry(master )
self.pathentry.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 6,   sticky = 'we') 
self.catentry = ttk.Entry(master )
self.catentry.grid(row = 2 , column = 1 ,   sticky = 'we') 
self.tableentry = ttk.Entry(master )
self.tableentry.grid(row = 2 , column = 4 ,   sticky = 'we')
```

Instead, group widget creating and widget layout separately. The layout of one widget can affect the layout of others. Those sorts of problems are much easier to solve when all of the layout is together.

My rule of thumb is to group all widgets that share the same master together, though that rule can be broken when it makes the code more readable to do it slightly differently.

For example:

```
self.pathentry = ttk.Entry(master )
self.catentry = ttk.Entry(master )
self.tableentry = ttk.Entry(master )

self.pathentry.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 6,   sticky = 'we') 
self.catentry.grid(row = 2 , column = 1 ,   sticky = 'we') 
self.tableentry.grid(row = 2 , column = 4 ,   sticky = 'we')
```

### Don't use variables when calling `grid` on the same line

Code like this doesn't do what you think:

```
self.clearbutton = ttk.Button(...).grid(...)
```

`self.clearbutton` will be `None`, and it implies that you will use the instance of the object in other places. `self.clearbutton` will always be `None` because that's what `.grid()` always returns. It's better to break the code into two lines, and then group the calls to `grid` together as mentioned earlier.